# send a SubviewTo Back

Tags: uiview, background, uiimage

I´m trying to fill my view with a background image, see code below.
Unfortunately the subview is in front of all the other objects afterwards what I don´t want.
I tried to send the subview to the back with line#3 but it still remains in front.

Any ideas what I´m doing wrong?

```
 UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]
                       initWithImage:[UIImage 
                          imageNamed:@"Background.png"]];
 [view addSubview:imageView];
 [imageView sendSubviewToBack:imageView];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call should be:

```
[view sendSubviewToBack:imageView];
```

The above, into human, translates as: "Hey view, send this subview of yours, to the background".

Most (if not all) of the methods for handling subviews, should be called directly to the view that holds the subview that you'll hand as an argument.

Also, next time, take a hint from the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html):

> **Discussion**
>
> This method moves the specified view to the beginning of the array of views in the subviews property.